# NullPointerException while filling an array from .txt

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

here's the deal, i need to fill an array from a .txt file. I'v used the Scanner class to read each line and from the Ints get a position for the token to be stored in the array:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aplicacion {

    static Elemento _tablero[][] = new Elemento[8][8];


    public static Elemento[][] Leertxt() throws FileNotFoundException,IOException
    { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Owner/Documents/UNIMET/Trimestre  5/Estructura de Datos/Proyecto 1a/src/inicio.txt"));

        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            String ln = sc.next();          

           if (ln.equals("Pared"))
        {
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            int j = sc.nextInt();

             _tablero[i][j] = new Pared(i,j);//crea una pared nueva
        } 
         else if (ln.equals("Fantasma"))    
          {
             int i = sc.nextInt();
             int j = sc.nextInt(); 

           _tablero[i][j] = new Fantasma(i,j);//crea un fantasma nuevo
      }
        else if (ln.equals("Vacio"))
        {
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            int j = sc.nextInt();

            _tablero[i][j] = new Vacio(i,j); //crea un vacio
        }


     }


       for(int i=0; i<_tablero.length;i++)
        {
          for(int j=0;j<_tablero.length;j++)
            {
               if (_tablero[i][j] instanceof Vacio)
               {
                 _tablero[i][j] = null; 

                 _tablero[i][j] = new Punto(i,j);
            }
        }
    }     return _tablero;
}  

public  void mostrar() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{   Elemento[][] tab = Leertxt(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
  { for(int j = 0;j < tab.length; j++)
      {
           System.out.print("  "+ tab[i][j].mostrar();
          }
       System.out.println();//salto de linea
      }
}
```

It compiles with no error, but when I run I end up getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Aplicacion.mostrar(Aplicacion.java:73)
    at JuegoPacman.main(JuegoPacman.java:27)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

I dont understand where is it getting the NullPointerException in line 73.
The mostrar method is an abstract method in the Elemento class and it just prints a symbol...any help would be happily accepted

Comment: There's only a single dereference in `mostrar()` ... you can pretty much deduce the line number from that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because when you attempt to call `tab[i][j].mostrar()` ... `tab[i][j]` is `null`. You never put an object in that location in the array.

There is nothing in your `Leertxt()` method that assures all 64 locations receive an object.

If you want to find out *which* location that is, change your loop to:

```
Elemento[][] tab = Leertxt(); 
for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
{ 
    for(int j = 0;j < tab[i].length; j++)
    {
        if (tab[i][j] == null)
            System.out.println("null at location: [" + i + "," + j + "]");
        else
            System.out.print("  "+ tab[i][j].mostrar();
    }
    System.out.println();//salto de linea
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up further on Brian Roach's comment, I suggest you add in to:

```
if (_tablero[i][j] instanceof Vacio)
```

To expand it to include nulls (I assume in empty space, you would also include null):

```
if (_tablero[i][j] instanceof Vacio || _tablero[i][j] == null)
```

So that if something is undefined in your text file, it will be defined here. If you want, you could even throw up a flag whenever it detects a null square to ensure that you track down the nulls.

The other option would be to surround:

```
System.out.print("  "+ tab[i][j].mostrar());
```

ie Problem line 73 with a try/catch block or a ternary operation:

```
try{
    System.out.print("  "+ tab[i][j].mostrar());
} catch (NullPointerException ex){
    //haz algo
}
```

Or

```
System.out.print("  "+ ((tab[i][j] == null) ? "null" : tab[i][j].mostrar()));
```